# an indefinite pronoun or a determiner

Tags: sentence-construction, parts-of-speech

In a dictionary, I happened upon some explanation.

> Only half of my friends could come to my party.

In this case, they say that the word “half” is a determiner.

I knew that is a indefinite pronoun. I don’t know what is correct.

And someone told me that in the sentence, NP(my friend) is omitted after the word “half” and in front of the PP(of my friend)

Is it true?

Comment: Fyi a pronoun don't take part in partitive construction.

Comment: "Half" belongs to the word category (part of speech) **noun**, and in your example its function is **head** of the topmost NP with a following partitive complement, i.e. "of my friends"